# integrating a 2DHistogram in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am an idiot with using python and jupyter notebook. It took me days to properly display a 2D Histogram of some data I collected. Now I want to integrate part of that 2DHistogram, so I can count some of the data points but not all. Below is the code I have so far, E and Eint are two arrays of data. Some of this is stuff I just copied from elsewhere because that's what another question on this site told me to do, so if it's a big waste of space, I'm happy to be told. Anyway, how do I integrate the plot within a certain band of x and y?

```
x_min=np.min(E)
x_max=1000

y_min=np.min(Eint)
y_max=0.6

x_bins=np.linspace(x_min,x_max,100)
y_bins=np.linspace(y_min,y_max,100)

fig, ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(10,7))

x_bins=100
y_bins=100

plt.hist2d(E,Eint, bins=[x_bins, y_bins], cmap=plt.cm.RdBu)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi - Can you pls post some sample data of E and Eint. Also, you mentioned that you were able to create a Histogram. So, what are you trying to achieve now? Can you pls be specific on what you were able to do and what more are you trying to achieve?